# Why gives my script an other output with the echo command?

Tags: batch-file

The output is not what I expected to get... especially the first piece of the output. I

think it goes wrong with the @ token. But I couldnt find anything about it and cant

figure it out.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong??

THNX

This is my script:

```
if not exist input.bat (
    echo @echo off > input.bat
    echo title Input >> input.bat
    echo :set >> input.bat
    echo MODE CON: COLS=29 LINES=5 >> input.bat
    echo :loop >> input.bat
    echo cls >> input.bat
    echo echo Gebruik de wasd toetsen >> input.bat
    echo echo om te bewegen >> input.bat
    echo echo a/Left d/Right >> input.bat
    echo choice /c:wscradp /n >> input.bat
    echo if ERRORLEVEL 6 ( >> input.bat
    echo echo d^>action.txt >> input.bat
    echo goto loop) >> input.bat
    echo if ERRORLEVEL 5 ( >> input.bat
    echo echo a^>action.txt >> input.bat
    echo goto loop) >> input.bat
    echo if ERRORLEVEL 4 ( >> input.bat
    echo echo r^>action.txt >> input.bat
    echo goto loop) >> input.bat
    echo if ERRORLEVEL 3 ( >> input.bat
    echo    taskkill /f /im cmd.exe >> input.bat
    echo    exit >> input.bat
    echo ) >> input.bat
    echo if ERRORLEVEL 2 ( >> input.bat
    echo echo s^>action.txt >> input.bat
    echo goto loop) >> input.bat
    echo if ERRORLEVEL 1 echo w^>action.txt >> input.bat
    echo goto loop >> input.bat
)
```

This is the output (the file input.bat) when input.bat doesn`t exist:

```
goto loop
if ERRORLEVEL 5 ( 
echo a>action.txt 
goto loop) 
if ERRORLEVEL 4 ( 
echo r>action.txt 
goto loop) 
if ERRORLEVEL 3 ( 
    taskkill /f /im cmd.exe 
    exit 
) 
if ERRORLEVEL 2 ( 
echo s>action.txt 
goto loop) 
if ERRORLEVEL 1 echo w>action.txt 
goto loop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(` and `)` must be also escaped with `^`.

The last page on entering `cmd.exe /?` in a command prompt window contains the list of special characters which have a special meaning in batch files and therefore require an escape character to be interpreted as literal character if not within a double quoted string.

```
if not exist input.bat (
    echo @echo off > input.bat
    echo title Input >> input.bat
    echo :set >> input.bat
    echo MODE CON: COLS=29 LINES=5 >> input.bat
    echo :loop >> input.bat
    echo cls >> input.bat
    echo echo Gebruik de wasd toetsen >> input.bat
    echo echo om te bewegen >> input.bat
    echo echo a/Left d/Right >> input.bat
    echo choice /c:wscradp /n >> input.bat
    echo if ERRORLEVEL 6 ^( >> input.bat
    echo echo d^>action.txt >> input.bat
    echo goto loop^) >> input.bat
    echo if ERRORLEVEL 5 ^( >> input.bat
    echo echo a^>action.txt >> input.bat
    echo goto loop^) >> input.bat
    echo if ERRORLEVEL 4 ^( >> input.bat
    echo echo r^>action.txt >> input.bat
    echo goto loop^) >> input.bat
    echo if ERRORLEVEL 3 ^( >> input.bat
    echo    taskkill /f /im cmd.exe >> input.bat
    echo    exit >> input.bat
    echo ^) >> input.bat
    echo if ERRORLEVEL 2 ^( >> input.bat
    echo echo s^>action.txt >> input.bat
    echo goto loop^) >> input.bat
    echo if ERRORLEVEL 1 echo w^>action.txt >> input.bat
    echo goto loop >> input.bat
)
```

Even better would be

```
if not exist input.bat (
    echo @echo off> input.bat
    echo title Input>> input.bat
    echo :set>> input.bat
    echo MODE CON: COLS=29 LINES=^5>> input.bat
    echo :loop>> input.bat
    echo cls>> input.bat
    echo echo Gebruik de wasd toetsen>> input.bat
    echo echo om te bewegen>> input.bat
    echo echo a/Left d/Right>> input.bat
    echo choice /c:wscradp /n>> input.bat
    echo if ERRORLEVEL 6 ^(>> input.bat
    echo echo d^>action.txt>> input.bat
    echo goto loop^)>> input.bat
    echo if ERRORLEVEL 5 ^(>> input.bat
    echo echo a^>action.txt>> input.bat
    echo goto loop^)>> input.bat
    echo if ERRORLEVEL 4 ^(>> input.bat
    echo echo r^>action.txt>> input.bat
    echo goto loop^)>> input.bat
    echo if ERRORLEVEL 3 ^(>> input.bat
    echo    taskkill /f /im cmd.exe>> input.bat
    echo    exit>> input.bat
    echo ^)>> input.bat
    echo if ERRORLEVEL 2 ^(>> input.bat
    echo echo s^>action.txt>> input.bat
    echo goto loop^)>> input.bat
    echo if ERRORLEVEL 1 echo w^>action.txt>> input.bat
    echo goto loop>> input.bat
)
```

This version with no space left of `>>` avoids a trailing space in created *input.bat* on every line. To get this version to work for all lines it is necessary to escape also `5` in line 5 or `5>>` would be interpreted instead of appending character 5 to the file.

Answer (score 1):

This is a more readable way to create the script:

Opening brackets don't need to be escaped.
You may also prefer to use `echo(` as it is more resistant to errors that occur from various leading characters, and it is faster.

```
@echo off
if not exist input.bat (
    (
    echo @echo off
    echo title Input
    echo :set
    echo MODE CON: COLS=29 LINES=5
    echo :loop
    echo cls
    echo echo Gebruik de wasd toetsen
    echo echo om te bewegen
    echo echo a/Left d/Right
    echo choice /c:wscradp /n
    echo if ERRORLEVEL 6 (
    echo echo d^>action.txt
    echo goto loop^)
    echo if ERRORLEVEL 5 (
    echo echo a^>action.txt
    echo goto loop^)
    echo if ERRORLEVEL 4 (
    echo echo r^>action.txt
    echo goto loop^)
    echo if ERRORLEVEL 3 (
    echo    taskkill /f /im cmd.exe
    echo    exit
    echo ^)
    echo if ERRORLEVEL 2 (
    echo echo s^>action.txt
    echo goto loop^)
    echo if ERRORLEVEL 1 echo w^>action.txt
    echo goto loop
    )>input.bat
)
```