# How to echo output redirection mark (>>) literally?

Tags: batch-file, echo

I'm creating a bat file that will write me a script that will be called by another bat.

What I wrote:

```
echo @echo off>>myscript-NTRE_TN_F
echo open 127.0.0.1>>myscript-NTRE_TN_F
echo user USER PASS>>myscript-NTRE_TN_F
echo prompt n>>myscript-NTRE_TN_F
echo ascii>>myscript-NTRE_TN_F
echo lcd C:\>>myscript-NTRE_TN_F

SET MAX_FILES=200
SET /S FILE_COUNT=0

for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2 delims=," %%a IN ("C:\filelist-NTRE_TN_F.txt") DO (
    IF !FILE_COUNT! LSS %MAX_FILES% (
        echo mget %%a>>myscript-NTRE_TN_F
        echo echo %%a>>C:\Downloaded_Files.txt>>myscript-NTRE_TN_F
    )
    SET /A FILE_COUNT+=1
)

echo bye>>myscript-NTRE_TN_F
```

My issue is in the `echo echo %%a` part.
My output now is:

```
@echo off
open 127.0.0.1
user USER PASS
prompt n
ascii
lcd C:\
mget FILE1
echo FILE1
mget FILE2
echo FILE2
bye
```

I would like an OUTPUT like this:

```
@echo off
open 127.0.0.1
user USER PASS
prompt n
ascii
lcd C:\
mget FILE1
echo FILE1>>C:\Downloaded_Files.txt"
mget FILE2
echo FILE2>>C:\Downloaded_Files.txt
bye
```

I found something similar in the topic here:
[Why gives my script an other output with the echo command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24826801/why-gives-my-script-an-other-output-with-the-echo-command)

I don't know how to manage the variable.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Why are you writing `@echo off`, which is a Command Prompt command, into an FTP script?

Comment: Yes you are totally right... this is what I'm discovering now trying the script... I have to understand how to do it because I need to write in a file tracing which file I've already downloaded. By the way thanks for your comment!
I think I figured out.

Comment: just for information I changed the echo and put outside the "myscript":  
    echo %%a>>C:\Downloaded_Files.txt    
    SET /A FILE_COUNT+=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using this batch code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "ScriptFile=myscript-NTRE_TN_F"
>"%ScriptFile%" echo @echo off
>>"%ScriptFile%" echo open 127.0.0.1
>>"%ScriptFile%" echo user USER PASS
>>"%ScriptFile%" echo prompt n
>>"%ScriptFile%" echo ascii
>>"%ScriptFile%" echo lcd C:\

SET "MAX_FILES=200"
SET "FILE_COUNT=0"

for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2 delims=," %%a IN ("C:\filelist-NTRE_TN_F.txt") DO (
    IF !FILE_COUNT! GEQ %MAX_FILES% goto Finish
    >>"%ScriptFile%" echo mget %%a
    set "ScriptLine=>>C:\Downloaded_Files.txt echo %%a"
    >>"%ScriptFile%" echo !ScriptLine!
    SET /A FILE_COUNT+=1
)

:Finish
>>"%ScriptFile%" echo bye
endlocal
```

The redirection operator can be also put at beginning of a line which makes it easier to read what is written into the file.

Inside the **FOR** loop the **IF** condition is changed to exit the loop on reaching value of `MAX_FILES`.

And the line to output is first assigned to a variable enclosed in double quotes to get `>>` interpreted as string and the value of this variable is output using delayed expansion with redirection to file.

Please read also answer on [Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564) for an explanation why using double quotes around `variable=value`.

See also the Microsoft article [Using command redirection operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx)

Another even better solution is:

```
@echo on
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "ScriptFile=myscript-NTRE_TN_F"
(
    echo @echo off
    echo open 127.0.0.1
    echo user USER PASS
    echo prompt n
    echo ascii
    echo lcd C:\
)>"%ScriptFile%"

SET "MAX_FILES=200"
SET "FILE_COUNT=0"

for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2 delims=," %%a IN ("C:\filelist-NTRE_TN_F.txt") DO (
    IF !FILE_COUNT! GEQ %MAX_FILES% goto Finish
    echo mget %%a
    set "ScriptLine=>>C:\Downloaded_Files.txt echo %%a"
    echo !ScriptLine!
    SET /A FILE_COUNT+=1
)>>"%ScriptFile%"

:Finish
echo bye>>"%ScriptFile%"
endlocal
```

All lines output to **STDOUT** within the two command blocks are redirected into the script file to create.

By the way: `SET /S FILE_COUNT=0` resulted on execution in error message

> The syntax of the command is incorrect.

The command **SET** does not support an option `/S`, just `/A` for an arithmetic expression and `/P` for prompting user for value if command extensions are enabled in current command process environment.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion and of expecially for the way you teach to me (newbie) how and why code in this way.
I'm using the suggestion so I accept your answer!
I just modified two lines to exclude the echo in the FTP script because I didn't need it inside.
Thank you again!!! Cheers

Answer (score 2):

(example)

```
    echo echo %%a^>^>C:\Downloaded_Files.txt>>myscript-NTRE_TN_F
```

The caret `^` signifies that the following character be reproduced literally.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I didn't know to use the ^ character!